# how to convert nsstring to nsarray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a string 
Afar,Abkhazian,Afrikaans,Amharic
and i wish to convert it into the NSArray. Currently i am using the code:

```
  NSArray *languagesuserArray = [self.languagesOfUser componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

But next when i checked like this:

```
NSLog(@"Languages array %@",[languagesuserArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

the output comes:

```
Afar,Abkhazian,Afrikaans,Amharic
```

But i want only afar.. How to do this?

Comment: `[self.languagesOfUser componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to seperate string by comma (,)  not with blank space as your original string contains comma seperator.

```
 NSArray *languagesuserArray = [self.languagesOfUser componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 NSLog(@"Languages array %@",[languagesuserArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: How can you this if the string doesn't have "," (commas)?

Comment: @user2924482 this answer is related to comma separator that's why I used comma here .. if you have another separator in string you can use that too even you can use blank space too.

Answer (score 1):

The languages are not separated by empty space, they are separated by commas. Now look at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!!

```
    NSString *myString = @"Address1, Address2";
    NSArray *myArray = [myString  componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString  *firstString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",firstString);
    NSString *secondString = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",secondString);
```